# Using SQL Server Compact Edition as a setup bundle

Tags: vb.net

I installed my test application on a computer that did not have any versions of SS installed on it.  I copied all the seven .dlls in the folder of the application but it gives an error.  I wonder why?

Please advise if it is a must to install the SSCE on the target computer?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit further on the issue and tell us which kind of error are you receiving, Sehgal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not a must to use the installer to deploy SSCE on the client computer. However, you have to follow various rules during development when deploying this way.

The primary rules are that your project must reference local copies of SSCE rather than the version in GAC and that the files be deployed next to the executing application on the target computer.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) has detailed information on both approaches.